# Copy some data from one set of related tables to another using ssis

Tags: ssis

I need to archive 10 days old data to archive database tables, can you please help me to understand how to copy data from one set of related tables to another, including dependent rows, while preserving the correct relationships between the rows.

This is a diagram that shows the data model for the source and target sets of tables:

[image: Source & Destination tables]

Same table structure at archive database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using a "Data Flow Task", probably one for each table. Simply start with the tables that do not have any dependencies (table A in your diagram) and copy the data from the source table to the target table using the appropriate data source and target components from the SSIS Toolbox. After that copy the data of tables that only depend on these first tables (table B) and so on.

If the primary key columns in your source tables are somehow computed (for example through using identity increments) their respective columns within the archive tables should be of the same data type, however, they should not be computed because this would mess with your dependencies. They can still be primary keys, though.

**Update:** Regarding the *10 days old* part: In your data source component you can use SQL queries to only read the specific rows you need. As long as you can make sure that the SSIS job does not start on one day and runs until after midnight (i.e. it completely runs on one day), you can calculate the date part in the `WHERE` conditions of these queries. A cleaner solution would be to calculate the date before the first data flow task and then pass it to each of the data flow tasks as a variable. That way you can make sure that all queries use the same date value.